# Overlapping images before refresh / on some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I followed and altered a tutorial for a landing page. I have had an issue where sometimes the first time the website loads on a browser it shows overlapping images, but if I refresh the browser or flip the screen (on mobile) it looks fine. The responsive dev tools also show it working fine on any browser.

I have tried altering the items shown per page in the JavaScript and playing with the tags img-fluid and image responsive.

```js
let toggle = document.querySelector("#header .toggle-button");
let collapse = document.querySelectorAll("#header .collapse");

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  collapse.forEach(col => col.classList.toggle("collapse-toggle"));
})

// with masonry
new Masonry("#posts .grid", {
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  gutter: 20
});

// swiper libray initialization
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 9,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 3000
  },
  // responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    '@0': {
      slidesPerView: 1

    },
    // 888px
    '@1.00': {
      slidesPerView: 1
    },
    // 1110px
    '@1.25': {
      slidesPerView: 2
    },
    // 1330px
    '@1.50': {
      slidesPerView: 3
    }
  }
})

// Sticky Navigation
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

// get the current value 
let navbar = document.getElementById("header");

// get the navbar position
let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// sticky function
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid .grid-item {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  .col-3 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
    padding-top: 40px 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: initial;
  }
  .collapse {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.51, -0.15, 0, 0.98);
  }
  .collapse .nav-link {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .search-box {
    border-right: none;
  }
  .collapse-toggle {
    max-height: 500px;
  }
  .grid .grid-item {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  #site-main {
    margin-top: 6em;
  }
}
```

```html
!--main site-->
<main id="site-main">

  <!-- Blog Post Section -->
  <section id="posts">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid">

        <!-- article -->
        <div class="grid-item">
          <article class="article">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="overflow-img">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="./Assets/IMG-1921.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body text-center px-1">
                <a href="#" class="text-title display-1 text-dark">
                                        Welcome to TylerTeacher.com
                                    </a>
                <p class="secondary-title text-secondary display-3">
                  <span><i class="far fa-clock text-primary"></i> Clock Wed 02, 2021</span>
                  <span><i class="far fa-comments text-primary"></i> 12</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't see a class named 'sticky' in your CSS, so I don't see much utility in toggling it in the JS. You probably want to add links to Bootstrap and Font Awesome CSS in your HTML. Also, there is no element with an id of `header` in the HTML, so that JavaScript is throwing an error. Please fix those if they apply to your issue; if not, remove them from the example; we're looking for a [mre].

Comment: `padding-top: 40px 50px;` is not valid CSS, maybe that would explain some browser-specific issues, choose either `40px` or `50px` for your `padding-top`